# Android BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) Connect/Disconnect/Reconnect

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

The Android BLE API seems odd, maybe I'm missing something.  What I need to do, is to make a connection to a BLE device, then if things are idle for a while disconnect temporarily, but when the user wants to do something new I want to reconnect.

To connect initially, I call:

```
Gatt1 = Device.ConnectGatt (Android.App.Application.Context, false, GattCallback);
```

Then I'm thinking to do my temporary disconnect I call

```
Gatt1.Disconnect();
```

And then when I want to re-connect, I call ConnectGatt() again, which gives me a new BluetoothGatt object:

```
Gatt2 = Device.ConnectGatt (Android.App.Application.Context, false, GattCallback);
```

So once I've called Gatt1.Disconnect(), I should just throw away Gatt1?  It's not useful anymore, since when I re-connect I get a new BluetoothGatt object?  Do I need to call some function to tell the API that I'm not using Gatt1 anymore?

(no, I wouldn't actually have two variables, Gatt1 and Gatt2, I'm just using those names to indicate there are two different objects happening)

When I eventually decided I'm completely done with this BLE device, I'm not planning on ever re-connecting, then I need to call Gatt.Close() (right?)

So maybe the code looks more like this?

```
BluetoothDevice Device = stuff();
BluetoothGatt Gatt = null;

if (connecting)
   Gatt = Device.ConnectGatt(...);
else if (disconnecting temporarily)
   Gatt.Disconnect();
else if (reconnecting after a temporary disconnection)
{
   Gatt = null;   // Yes?  Do I need to specifically Dispose() this previous object?
   Gatt = Device.ConnectGatt(...);
}
else if (disconnecting permanently)
{
   Gatt.Close();
   Gatt = null;
}
```

(again, no, I wouldn't write such a function, it's just to illustrate the lifespan of the various BluetoothGatt objects)

Comment: May I ask why do you need two gatt objects if you are connecting to one device at a time?

Comment: I don't.  Initially I didn't see the BluetoothGatt.Connect() function, so I thought I had to call BluetoothDevice.ConnectGatt() a second time - generating a second BluetoothGatt object.  I now see that's not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You need to also dispose the first BluetoothGatt object (Gatt1) when you are done with it, by calling the close() method on it. Just leaving the garbage collection to clean it up will *not* work I guess since it has no finalizer which calls the internal Bluetooth stack to clean it. If you don't close the object and just drop the reference, you will eventually run out of BluetoothGatt objects (there can be max 32 totally on the device for all apps together).

Answer (score 0):

```
Gatt1 = Device.ConnectGatt (Android.App.Application.Context, false, GattCallback);
```

should be followed by:

```
Gatt1.connect();
```

Gatt1.disconnect() is correct for your purposes. When reconnecting, Gatt1 = null is unnecessary. Just call device.connectGatt() and Gatt1.connect() again. When you're completely done:

```
if(Gatt1!=null) {
     Gatt1.disconnect();
     Gatt1.close();
}
```

Comment: In my testing, I don't need _both_ ConnectGatt() and connect().

Comment: @BettyCrokker Ah yes, my bad. Connect() should just be used afterwards upon reconnecting.

Answer (score 0):

After reading these suggestions, and doing some more research, I think the answer is this:

```
BluetoothDevice Device = stuff();
BluetoothGatt Gatt = null;

if (connecting)
   Gatt = Device.ConnectGatt(...);
else if (disconnecting temporarily)
   Gatt.Disconnect();
else if (reconnecting after a temporary disconnection)
   Gatt.Connect();
else if (disconnecting permanently)
{
   Gatt.Disconnect();
   Gatt.Close();
   Gatt = null;
}
```

with a bunch of additional code to wait for the connect/disconnect actions to finish.